# Emulator sometimes fails to hit webservices no error as well as no response

Tags: android, web-services, websocket, android-emulator, timeout

I am using Droid4x emulator to run application. In my application I am doing 2way communication. App connected with server through Socket.io, from Socket.io on message function I am  post message to other server through webservices http call. Sometimes it's is working fine After sometimes till socket message function working then it's calling asynchronous task also but no response as well as no error. It is not post message to other server.

Comment: Did you checked while its fails socket connection established or not? Because some time of frame socket connection disconnected you need to hit connection request again once its fails

Comment: Yes I checked. socket is connected only... Message also receiving. problem is after receiving message not posting to another server (web service http asynchronous task)

Comment: receiving message not  posting to another service?

Comment: Yes. But sometimes posting...

Comment: what do you mean by another server ? i didnt  get  you